# How can I store request specific 'global' variable in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, global-variables

I would like to setup a global variable that is accessible across the CakePHP application (in Controllers, Models and View). The variable value can be different for each request coming into the application. What is the best way to set this up?

Some options I thought of:

1. Use Configure::write in bootstrap.php to set-up this variable and Configure::read anywhere to read the value. I am not sure if this is the best option as I couldn't find any clear documentation on the scope of the Configure array. It appears that Configure is typically used for site-wide/application wide variables so not sure if each HTTP request will have its own Configure array or not.
2. Write this value in the $GLOBALS array from within bootstrap.php. Is this a good idea? Can't think of any downsides but seems using $GLOBALS is not encouraged.
3. Export or set a global variable somehow from bootstrap.php which is scoped for a request and thread-safe and available across the application for that request. Don't know how/if this is possible.

Please help!

Comment: @pleasedontbelong sure, sessions is a solution - although not ideal since I don't want the state to be maintained across requests (which sessions typically are used for). Looking for something which only automatically lasts for a HTTP request-response scope for each request.

Comment: Have you considered adding it to the [CakeRequest](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html) object? The current request can easily be accessed throughout your application. Although I wonder if this information should be "retrieved" from within your model, or "passed to" the model (I'd generally prefer to pass the information to your model as a parameter, which is a cleaner approach)

Answer (score 3):

Configure is you friend here:

in AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    parent::beforeFilter();
    Configure::write('you_variable', 'your_value');

}
```

You can read the value anywhere in your app (Controllers, Models, Views) with

```
Configure::read('your_variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have public variable in your AppController , and give value to it in beforeFilter() function.
Something like this

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    /**
     * The dependency components needed
     * @var array An array of component names
     */
    public $components = array(
        'Cookie',
        'Session',
        'Auth',
    );

    /**
     * The dependency Models needed
     * @var array An array of model names
    */
    public $uses = array(
        'User'
        );

    /**
     * Your variable
    */
    public $yourVariable = null;



    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->yourVariable = 'Your request specific data';            
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't help since I need access to the variable in Models and Views - not just Controllers

Comment: This will work only in controllers , I have missed out part that you want use it in models too. 
You can define it in /app/webroot/index.php like other variables like WWW_ROOT defined

Comment: For views it will work you need only to set it to view $this->set('yourVariable', $this->yourVariable)

Comment: "I need access to the variable in Models" - you may ask your self if the Model should 'actively' retrieve that variable or that it should be passed as an argument, e.g. `$this->Model->findSomething("something", $yourSpecialVariable);`. Using this approach, you'll leave the 'Controller' in control :D